# How do I delete ".project" file from Git?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

By mistake I have committed **.project** file in git from Eclipse. As this file name starts with a dot it is not visible in git files in Eclipse. How do I delete it from git using Eclipse?

Comment: In command line: `git rm .project`, then commit the deletion and that's all

Comment: [Eclipse has its own Git implementation](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/). There is no Git command line unless [Git](https://git-scm.com/) has been installed independent from Eclipse.

Answer (score 7):

If you already have a file checked in, and you want to ignore it, Git will not ignore the file if you add a rule later. In those cases, you must untrack the file first, by running the following command in your terminal:

```
git rm --cached FILENAME
```

There is a file named as *.gitignore* in your project directory.
If not, you can create a new file in your project directory and name the file as '*.gitignore*'. 
Write in file -> '.project' and save.
Now try pushing your code up. I hope it works.
This file is essentially to ignore all the files mentioned while sync on GIT.

Answer (score 3):

1. In the ***Navigator*** view **right-click** the file **`.project`** and choose ***Team > Advanced > Untrack***
2. **Right-click** the file **`.project`** again and choose ***Team > Ignore***
3. Commit and push the changes

Answer (score 2):

Instead off deleting .project file (as it is used by IDE) you should probably ignore .project file by adding it to exclude file

Location of exclude file

```
.git/info/exclude
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `git rm` directly.

More here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm